# What happens when I run out of memory to maintain the state with mapWithState

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a very large number of keys and limited cluster size. 
I am using `mapWithState` to update my states. As new data comes in the number of keys increases. When I went to the storage tab of the spark UI `MapWithStateRDD` is always stored in memory.

In line 109 of the source code [MapWithStateDstream.Scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/MapWithStateDStream.scala)
the method persist is called when storage level is set to MEMORY_ONLY.
Does this mean my application will crash if I have too many keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i went to the storage tab of the spark UI MapWithStateRDD is
>   always stored in memory

Spark uses it's own implementation of a `HashMap` called `OpenHashMapBasedStateMap` to internally store the state. This means that the values are stored *in memory*, and not in a persistent store.

> Does this mean my application will crash if I have too many keys?

This means that your cluster needs to have sufficient resources to store all the keys simultaneously since the state is persisted *in-memory*. If you're limited, you'll need to optimize the state you save to make sure they all fit in. Otherwise, consider using an external persistent storage for your state.